# How can I get Python3 to calculate two numbers when the user presses <enter> or clicks the calculate button without using two separate def functions?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, calculation, tkinter-entry

I have searched for hours and can't find a simple explanation.  If I try to use just one function I can get the button to work but then the  key gives me an error message: and if I get the  key to work then the button gives me an error message: .  This seems silly there must be a simple way to get both the  key and the button to both access the same function without causing an argument error.  Here is my working code right now which unfortunately uses two calculate functions to avoid the argument error messages. Thanks for any help.

```
"""
Description: This is a program creates a simple GUI for a user to add 2 numbers

Author: Paul Heffernan

Date: Feb 10, 2021
"""

# Import the tkinter GUI and call tkinter tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

# This function adds two numbers together when <enter> is pressed in entry2
def addNumbersEntry(self, *args):
    result=int(e1.get())+int(e2.get())
    myText.set(result)

# This function adds two numbers together when the calculate button is clicked
def addNumbersBtn():
    result=int(e1.get())+int(e2.get())
    myText.set(result)

# This funciton moves the cursor from entry1 to entry2 when <enter> is pressed
def go_to_entry2(event):
    e2.focus_set() # focus_set() switches the focus to the new widge
    
# create a window and call it window, then give it a title and preset size
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('The Two Number Calculator')
window.minsize(width=400, height=300)
window.resizable(width=True, height=True)

# Create a special GUI StringVar to hold info for a widget - a simple String will not work
myText=StringVar()
myText.set('Nothing Yet')

# Create labels and two entry widgets for user input
lbl1 = Label(master=window, text="Number 1:")
e1 = Entry(master=window)
e1.bind('<Return>', go_to_entry2)
lbl2 = Label(master=window, text="Number 2:")
e2 = Entry(master=window)
e2.bind('<Return>', addNumbersEntry)
lbl3 = Label(master=window, text="Result:")
result = Label(master=window, text="", textvariable=myText)
b = Button(master=window, text="Calculate", command=addNumbersBtn)

# add the label and entry to the window
lbl1.pack()
e1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
e2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
result.pack()
b.pack()

# Run the application
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please check if you are giving correct arguments to `addNumbersEntry()` as I'm not sure why a `self` is passed there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same function for `command` option of button and `.bind()` callback:

```py
def addNumbers(*args):
    result=int(e1.get())+int(e2.get())
    myText.set(result)

...
e2.bind('<Return>', addNumbers)
...
b = Button(master=window, text="Calculate", command=addNumbers)
...
```

Comment: That works great, thanks for the help.  Mind you now I have to figure out why it works.  What is the difference between def addNumbers() which works for a button, vs def addNumbers(*args) which works for both a button and an <enter> key vs def addNumbers(self, *args).  I will have to do more research.  Thanks again.

Comment: `def addNumber(*args)` means that `addNumber()` function accepts any number of arguments.